# star-compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ is said to be **star compact** if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

$St(K, \mathscr{U})=\cup\{u\in \mathscr{U}: u \cap K \neq \emptyset\}$

If P is a topological property, then a space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be **minimal $P$** (respectively, maximal) if $(X, \tau)$ has property $P$ but no topology on $X$ which is strictly smaller (respectively, strictly larger ) than τ has P.

> 1: Let $(X, \tau_1)$ be a star-compact topological space and $\tau_2  \subset \tau_1$.**Is $(X , \tau_2)$ a  star-compact topological space?**

we know that Hausdorff compact space is minimal Hausdorff or maximal compact.

> 2:Is there relation between  (minimal)Hausdorff  and maximal star-compact?
>    I mean, is it possible to deduce from (minimal) Hausdorff a star maximal compact space Or vice versa?
>   If there is no relation, what conditions are needed to let Hausdorff's space become a maximal star  compact ?

Answer (score 1):

The first question seems rather easy:

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a $\tau_2$-open cover of $X$, which is also a $\tau_1$-open cover of $X$ (as $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$). So there is a $\tau_1$-compact $K$ with $\operatorname{St}(K, \mathcal{U}) = X$. But $K$ is also $\tau_2$-compact so we are done and the same $K$ shows that $(X, \tau_2)$ is star compact.